# Microsoft bot: How to log each conversation step?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm learning how to build a Microsoft Bot and I need to send every message (ie log the user progress through the bot) to an API.

Let's say I have these dialogs with 3 steps each:

- `/`
- `/welcome`
- `/onboarding`
- `/finish`

When a user joins the conversation (Root dialog), I need to make a POST to our API with the following data:

`{
  "conversationId": "8n21b2mkmdb9abi26",
  "dialog": "root", 
  "step": 1
}`

And then, for each following user message, I would update that conversation in our server with the dialog and step.

I tried to use the [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-intercept-messages) hook, but it doesn't have the information of which dialog/step the user is currently in.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middleware feature gives you access to the `session` object. Store the metadata you need in the `session` object, then access it in your logging middleware.

For a code example, check out: [Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples - Middleware and Logging with BotBuilder Node SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/capability-middlewareLogging)

Comment: Though this will work, I thought we could do this without too much duplication. Thank you @Nils.